# How to add new table to Debezium MySQL connector?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have Debezium MySQL connector:

```
{
    "name": "debezium_mysql",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "***",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "kafkaconnect",
        "database.password": "${file:/connect-credentials.properties:mysql_pass}",
        "database.server.name": "mysql",
        "heartbeat.interval​.ms": 5000,
        "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
        "database.include.list": "compare_sports",
        "table.include.list": "compare_sports.matches,compare_sports.games",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "mysql_compare_sports_history",
        "database.history​.kafka.recovery​.poll.interval.ms": 5000,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "***:9092",
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "transforms": "extractInt",
        "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractInt.field": "id"
    }
}
```

And I want to add new table (which exists for a long time) from other database in the same mysql. After adding it to include list, I am getting error:

```
Encountered change event for table new_database.new_table whose schema isn't known to this connector
```

I've tried to create new connector, with `snapshot.mode: initial` but then only new `mysql_history` topic is created but no desired `new_database.new_table` topic

What should I do to add to existing connector new table from new database?

Thanks

Comment: You need to have the table listed as `schemaName.tableName` for this configuration item

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new connector and set the `snapshot` to `initial` and specify a different `database.server.id`

Since the table already exists, you should include a `snapshot.override` as well as the default implementation will **select all rows** in the existing table which will hold a lock and prevent writers from writing into the database. You definitely don't want to do this.

```json
{
    ...
    "snapshot.mode"="initial",
    "database.server.id": "different",
    "snapshot.select.statement.overrides":"new-table",
    "snapshot.select.statement.new-table":"select * .. where <>"
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the same connector name, you'd have to stop it and manually clear its offset in the internal `connect.offsets.storage` topic. Then, when the connector is recreated (with the same name), it will restore its offsets based on the snapshot configuration that you have provided.

For more such cases, you can go through this [blog](https://aman-garg.medium.com/fixing-debezium-connectors-when-they-break-on-production-49fb52d6ac4e) (disc: I'm the author)

Answer (score 1):

Since debezium:1.6 you should be able to send a signal to snapshot the newly added table.
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/configuration/signalling.html
https://debezium.io/blog/2021/05/06/debezium-1-6-alpha1-released/

Sending a signal is done via inserting a record in a specific table:

```sql
INSERT INTO myschema.debezium_signal VALUES('ad-hoc-1', 'execute-snapshot', '{"data-collections": ["schema1.table1", "schema1.table2"]}')
```

And to make this feature available you should first create this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE debezium_signal (id VARCHAR(42) PRIMARY KEY, type VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, data VARCHAR(2048) NULL);
```

* syntax may differ between database types

Also the signal table must be added among the captured data collections, i.e., included in the `table.include.list` parameter.